# Prove $ (∀x_1 (∃x_2 (p(x_1, x_2) ⇒ (∀x_2 p(x_1, x_2)))))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, hilbert-calculus

Can u help show that this is a theorem? $ (∀x_1 (∃x_2 (p(x_1, x_2) ⇒ (∀x_2 p(x_1, x_2)))));$

I was trying to use the deduction theorem but i hit a wall. Can u help me out using derivatives and Hilbert Calculus?

Comment: It is good that you used parenthesis to disambiguate the expression, but they way you placed them, your second $x_2$ is over writing the first $x_2$, I think that is might be a typographical error.

Comment: @DanielV: No, that's how it's supposed to go. The body of the $\forall x_1$ is an instance of the [Drinker paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox).

Comment: @HenningMakholm It still should be $\forall x_3(p(x_1,\,x_3))$ (say), though.

Comment: See the post [Proof of Drinker paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807092/proof-of-drinker-paradox) as well as the post [Why is this true? (∃x)(P(x)⇒(∀y)P(y))](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py)

Comment: @J.G.: You could _also_ write that. But most formalizations of first-order logic do allow a quantifier to re-bind a variable that is already bound by an enclosing quantifier -- for reasons discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891491/why-not-ban-nested-quantifiers-over-the-same-variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/how-to-show-that-vdash-forall-x-beta-to-alpha-leftrightarrow-exists-x) you can find an Hilbert-style proof of :

> $⊢(∀xβ → α) ↔ ∃x(β → α)$, provided that $x$ is not *free* in $\alpha$.

We have to consider :

> $∀x_2p(x_1,x_2) \to ∀x_2p(x_1,x_2)$;

it is an instance of the propositional tautology : $\vdash A \to A$, and thus is a theorem.

Now we apply the equivalence above to it, due to the fact that $x_2$ is not free in $∀x_2p(x_1,x_2)$ to get :

> > $\vdash ∃x_2 \ (p(x_1,x_2) \to ∀x_2p(x_1,x_2))$.

The last step is obtained with Generalization:

> > $\vdash ∀x_1 \ ∃x_2 \ (p(x_1,x_2) \to ∀x_2p(x_1,x_2))$.

Answer (score 1):

"English" answer:

Fix any $x_1,\,x_2$. If $p(x_1,\,x_2)$ is false, the required implication is vacuously true. If $x_2$ cannot be chosen so that $p(x_1,\,x_2)$ is false, our choice of $x_1$ has obtained $\forall x_2 (p(x_1,\,x_2))$, so again the implication succeeds.

HC answer:

$$\exists x_2(\neg p(x_1,\,x_2))\implies(p(x_1,\,x_2)\implies \forall x_3 (p(x_1,\,x_3)))$$
$$\not\exists x_2(\neg p(x_1,\,x_2))\implies\forall x_3(p(x_1,\,x_3)),\,\implies(p(x_1,\,x_2)\implies\forall x_3(p(x_1,\,x_3)))$$
Then use $(q\implies r)\land (\neg q\implies r)\implies r$.

Comment: Yeah Thanks , but i was trying to do it using a sequece of derivatives with hilbert calculus.

Comment: @PedroSantos I hope my edit is a little bit more useful.